# Angular2: Show everything for empty filter pipe

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a filter pipe, where filtered result is shown on user input in a text field. It is working fine except when nothing is entered in the filter. If nothing is entered, none of the items from the list is shown. This is not I want, the desired behavior should be that every item in the list should be shown.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

**The HTML File**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Search Your Contacts" type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterFn">

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><h4>Contacts:</h4>
    <app-contact-item class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let contact of contacts | filter: filterFn; let i = index" [contact]="contact" [contactId]="i"></app-contact-item>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit()">Add New Contact</button>
</div>
```

**TS Component File**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {ContactService} from "./contact.service";
import {Contact} from "./contact";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
})
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() filterFn: string = '';
  contacts: Contact[] = [];

  constructor(private contactService: ContactService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contacts = this.contactService.getContacts();
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/contacts/new']);
  }

}
```

**TS Filter Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if(args[0] === '') {
      return value;
    }
    if(value.length === 0) {
      return value;
    }
    let filteredArray = [];
    for(let item of value) {
      if(item['firstName'].match('^.*' + args[0] + '.*$')) {
        filteredArray.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filteredArray;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your pipe as below :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.filter((item) => {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty('firstName')) {
        if(args.length) {
          return args[0] ? item.firstName.match('^.*' + args[0] + '.*$') : true;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Filtering doesn't happen when I enter something in the text field.

Comment: Try after checking this gist https://gist.github.com/ranakrunal9/092d6b930ede855e59e82c0f429fd562 once and change your pipe